# fit various div element, with various size, to entire container width

Tags: css, css-float

I've a div container within various floating div elements: I'd like to have some ones with a large width (big), others with a small width (small); at the same time, all of them should fit the entire container width. The number of small, big and total element are dynamically set via javascript, so I cannot use a fixed percentage width in css.

In some GUI developers software there are stretch values to achieve this goal.

Example (static) html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="small">small</div>
    <div class="big">BIG</div>
    <div class="big">BIG</div>
    <div class="big">BIG</div>
    <div class="small">small</div>
</div>
```

Example css:

```
.container {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%; }

.big , .small {
    float: left; }
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, how can we help you ? Your answer do not contain any question or demand.

Comment: @Eria, I think that the question is understood

Comment: @Paulie_D my code is a little more complicated, here I've written a simplified version that is the crux of my problem. I did researches but I cannot find anything. My attempts are totally useless, and my current idea is that my problem cannot be solved without use javascript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1: CSS Flex-box**

You can use CSS flex-box for this:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
}
    
.big {
  flex-grow:2;
  background-color:red;
}

.small {
  flex-grow:1;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="small">small</div>
    <div class="big">BIG</div>
    <div class="big">BIG</div>
    <div class="big">BIG</div>
    <div class="small">small</div>
</div>
```

**Option 2: JavaScript**

You could create a JS method that calculates the total width needed, and set the css style compared to that.

**Theory:**

```
Small = 1 width
Big = 2 width
```

Look at this link to count items in your div:
https://api.jquery.com/length/

```
4x big = 8 width
5x small = 5 width
total width = 13 width

width per small  in % = 100 / 13
width per large  in % = 100 / 13 * 2
```

set that width (eg. with JQuery)

Comment: Thanks, I know but I'm looking for a solution without modifying javascript code.

Comment: The flexbox goes with this principle you asked for. It looks at the complete width and depending on how much flex-grow you give your element, it stretches it to the appropriate size. Try the code and add div's, you will see if you add a thousand it still works.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks randy, I'm beginner in css!